# How to wrap tag by another tag?

Tags: javascript

How to wrap tag by another tag? For example:

```
<ul>
  <li>Html Tutorial</li>
  <li>Mongodb Tutorial</li>
  <li>Python Tutorial</li>
</ul>
```

I want to wrap second `li` element with `b` tag. How to do that?

Comment: You want to wrap the second **l**ist **i**tem with what?

Comment: Edited have a look, please.

Comment: Is it a "must" to wrap the element with a **b**old tag or are you wanting to make the second **l**ist **i**tem bold because this can be done using `css`. Here is a example of the `css` method [**JsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/ctoomh39/)

Comment: you have to search before ask :)

Comment: Of course I searched.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can easily do this

**// element that will be wrapped**

```
var el = document.querySelector('li:nth-child(2)');
```

**// create wrapper container**

```
var wrapper = document.createElement('b');
```

**// insert wrapper before el in the DOM tree**

```
el.parentNode.insertBefore(wrapper, el);
```

**// move el into wrapper**

```
wrapper.appendChild(el);
```

## Code Snippet

```js
// element that will be wrapped
var el = document.querySelector('li:nth-child(2)');

// create wrapper container
var wrapper = document.createElement('b');

// insert wrapper before el in the DOM tree
el.parentNode.insertBefore(wrapper, el);

// move el into wrapper
wrapper.appendChild(el);
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Html Tutorial</li>
  <li>Mongodb Tutorial</li>
  <li>Python Tutorial</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I know OP asked for "wrapping", but wrapping `li` tag with another tag is not standard, better use inner wrapp like this: `li b`. Because it will broke `li` style

Comment: I know. but hes asking for wrapping the li :) we should not distract him with another thing. but i'm completely agree with you about the standards.

Answer (score 2):

You mean this?

```
<li><b>Mongodb Tutorial</b></li>
```

Or In Javascript, assuming this is the only ul on the page.  You should probably put an ID on it.

```
var middleOne = document.querySelectorAll( 'ul > *' )[1];
middleOne.innerHTML = "<B>" + middleOne.innerHTML + "</B>";
```

Answer (score 2):

Wrapping `li` tag with another tag except `ul` or `ol` is not a good practice. You have many approach ahead but in below you can find two of them. One by `css` and the another one with pure `js`.

**CSS**:

```
ul li:nth-of-type(2) {font-weight:bold;}
/* or */
ul li:nth-child(2) {font-weight:bold;}
```

**JS**:

```
var ul = document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0];
var nth = ul.getElementsByTagName("li")[1];
nth.innerHTML = "<b>"+ nth.innerHTML +"</b>";
```

**P.S**: If you really need to wrapp `li` element with `b` tag try others answers. (but it is wrong structure)